# Why call it STICK and NOT_STICKY?

Tags: android

I've been reading awhile about [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService). I couldn't make the sense of naming different flags for starting services namely, START_NOT_STICKY and START_STICKY. At least, START_REDELIVER_INTENT is sensible but I having difficulty on understanding those two terms just by looking at their names alone.

What is etymology behind those semantics? This is to make myself associated with those words and how they work instead of just reading the docs. I am actually confused by the names TBH.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As per this documentation, STICKY is an analogy to indicate that the service *persists* despite getting killed, hence sticky. NOT_STICKY indicates that if the service gets killed, it is not recreated unless it has pending intents.

Hence the term *STICKY* has to do with the *persistence* of the said service.

Answer (score 0):

It indicate whether the service should run again if it become stopped or if any exception happen!

when you pass `STICKY` , if the service become terminated, it will be recreated again with the same intent you passed to it. This way you are sure your service is always running in background.

`NOT_STICKY` is completely different from `STICKY`.The service won't start again if it become terminated.